# Can Flutter be used to create a CMMS application?

Tags: flutter, xamarin, xamarin.forms, content-management-system, multiplatform

I have made a CMMS (Computerized Maintenance management) on Xamarin, I have Database that contains all the machines in a factory and each machine has multiple properties, the user can add a machine and choose the type ( from pre-defined types set in the database) and choose the value for each property related to this machine, the app also supports functionalities like, deleting elements, duplicating, copy/paste, cut/paste. (For example each factory has multiple locations each location is in a city, each city has multiple buildings, each building has multiple floor and each floor has multiple rooms and each room has multiple elements, and when choosing a location the elements in this location are loaded.

Also the app should work online and offline.

so for an application like this, would be possible to do it in flutter and would be reliable?

**It should work on both android and IOS**

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  This question is off-topic.

Comment: How is this off-topic? I gave complete description about my application to know if it is possible to do on flutter

Answer (score 0):

Flutter, like any frontend framework, can be used to create any app you want.